# send email through the ip address

Tags: c#, email, smtp, send

I want to send an email with C#. 
I am able to send email from mail.gmail.com however I couldn't send email from my company's smtp server .  I'm getting error x.x.x.x IP actively refused but this IP is not our smtp server ip . How can I use ip address instead of host name of smtp server.
Here is my code:

```
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("");
 mail.From = new MailAddress("");
 mail.To.Add("");
 mail.Subject = "";
 mail.Body="ollaa";
 SmtpServer.Port = 25;
 SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials=true;
 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

 try
 {
     SmtpServer.Send(mail);
 }

 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());               
 }
```

Comment: Put the IP Address between the quotes in the first line.

Comment: The `SmtpClient` instance needs to be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("12.12.22.12");
```

Comment: I tried it before but it didnt work again. Are we sure my code is okey?

Comment: the constructor can be either host name or IP.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.host(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `SmtpClient` has two overloads, `(string host)` and `(string host, int port)`.  You can either put in the IP address of your mail server in there, or better yet, use the host name.

Comment: Add the hostname to your hosts file if you must